# How to position apps inside weston compositor?

Tags: qt, qml, wayland, qtwayland

I am using weston compositor to display / run my qml app . but inside compositor app is starting in unpredictable area , which is why part of the apps gets hidden sometimes. Each launch , starts app in a new area. Is it possible to specify particular starting area for app inside weston compositor?

Comment: Did you try to set position manually with `Window.x` and `Window.y`? Also, as I remember setting `Window.flags` to `Qt.Dialog` places it in center of screen

Comment: @folibis: Setting the window position won't work, a client is not allowed to set, or even know, its own position on Wayland. (At least not with `xdg-shell` or `wl-shell`).